# voIP audio integration without specifc API or integration

Tags: python, integration, voip

I'm a aspiring developer, and currently learning Python and node on my free time as a new hobby. I really like it. I'm currently working on a project, and I haven't really found a solution and hope if someone here could help me how I can solve this problem.

So I'm working on a Q&A bot that is connected various voIP systems. Looking at the voIP system there's so many companies, and I'm wondering how I can connect the audio output from current calls directly in to my software without using any API or other integrations.

Is that possible? For instance Twillio (voIP) has a API integration, though creating an integration for every program would be a huge project. Is it possible to create an integration directly to the OS to fetch the incoming sound from the output of the voIP software?

How would you solve this?

A nice answer that can help me.